# Wide to long returns empty output - Python dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, melt

I have a dataframe which can be generated from the code as given below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id' :[1,2,3],'date1': 
['12/31/2007','11/25/2009','10/06/2005'],'val1': 
[2,4,6],'date2': ['12/31/2017','11/25/2019','10/06/2015'],'val2':[1,3,5],'date3': 
['12/31/2027','11/25/2029','10/06/2025'],'val3':[7,9,11]})
```

I followed the below solution to convert it from wide to long

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['date', 'val'], i='person_id', 
j='grp').sort_index(level=0)
```

Though this works with sample data as shown below, it doesn't work with my real data which has more than 200 columns. Instead of person_id, my real data has subject_ID which is values like DC0001,DC0002 etc. Does "I" always have to be numeric? Instead it adds the stub values as new columns in my dataset and has zero rows

This is how my real columns looks like

[image]

My real data might contains NA's as well. So do I have to fill them with default values for wide_to_long to work?

[image]

Can you please help as to what can be the issue? Or any other approach to achieve the same result is also helpful.

Comment: Copy and pasting your code here gave me your desired output, which you mentioned, so it would be better for us to be able to reproduce your problem (and therefore better diagnose it) if your sample data better matched your real data.

Comment: updated the screenshot of my actual columns if that can help anyway

Comment: That updated screenshot helps a lot. If I rename your columns to match the update, then I get an empty dataframe. I'd suggest renaming your columns so that the time points are at the end. For example, `'H1Date'` becomes `HDate1` or `Date1`, something like that.

Comment: So, I have more than 200 columns. Can you let me know how can I change this?I am starting off and your input would really be helpful

Comment: Sure, is it correct to assume that all columns can be sorted into 3 groups, HDate, HDerived, and H?

Comment: Yes. These 3 columns keep repeating with different numbers. They are in a sequence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195697/discussion-between-avles-and-hs-nebula).

Comment: a somewhat similar (but not exact) query was asked here>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657365/pivot-dataframe-with-duplicate-values. I trust, the solution is not working, maybe due to duplicate columns in your real dataset

Comment: @SirajS. Any other approach to do the same? I mean instead of wide_to_long

Answer (score 4):

Try adding additional argument in the function which allows the strings suffix.

```
pd.long_to_wide(.......................,suffix='\w+')
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your column names, the numbers used to convert from wide to long need to be at the end of your column names or you need to specify a suffix to groupby. I think the easiest solution is to create a function that accepts regex and the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def change_names(df, regex):
    # Select one of three column groups
    old_cols = df.filter(regex = regex).columns
    # Create list of new column names
    new_cols = []
    for col in old_cols:
        # Get the stubname of the original column
        stub = ''.join(re.split(r'\d', col))
        # Get the time point
        num = re.findall(r'\d+', col) # returns a list like ['1']
        # Make new column name
        new_col = stub + num[0]
        new_cols.append(new_col)

    # Create dictionary mapping old column names to new column names
    dd = {oc: nc for oc, nc in zip(old_cols, new_cols)}
    # Rename columns
    df.rename(columns = dd, inplace = True)

    return df


tdf = pd.DataFrame({'person_id' :[1,2,3],'h1date': ['12/31/2007','11/25/2009','10/06/2005'],'t1val': [2,4,6],'h2date': ['12/31/2017','11/25/2019','10/06/2015'],'t2val':[1,3,5],'h3date': ['12/31/2027','11/25/2029','10/06/2025'],'t3val':[7,9,11]})

# Change date columns
tdf = change_names(tdf, 'date$')
tdf = change_names(tdf, 'val$')

print(tdf)
    person_id      hdate1  tval1      hdate2  tval2      hdate3  tval3
0          1  12/31/2007      2  12/31/2017      1  12/31/2027      7
1          2  11/25/2009      4  11/25/2019      3  11/25/2029      9
2          3  10/06/2005      6  10/06/2015      5  10/06/2025     11
```

Comment: You mean does wide_to_long expect columns to have numbers at the end of their name? Does this give the output? When I modified the column names to have numbers at the end, it didn't help?

Comment: I think for your case, that'd be the easiest fix, but generally not necessarily, looking at the last example [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html).

Comment: But still this returns 0 records.

Comment: I don't know why it returns zero records still. I don't really know what's the issue? Can you help me implement this with melt approach or any other approach?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123924/convert-pandas-dataframe-from-wide-to-long) then and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite late to answer this question. But putting the solution here in case someone else find it useful

```
    tdf = pd.DataFrame({'person_id' :[1,2,3],'h1date': ['12/31/2007','11/25/2009','10/06/2005'],'t1val': [2,4,6],'h2date': ['12/31/2017','11/25/2019','10/06/2015'],'t2val':[1,3,5],'h3date': ['12/31/2027','11/25/2029','10/06/2025'],'t3val':[7,9,11]})
    
    ## You can use m13op22 solution to rename your columns with numeric part at the 
    ## end of the column name. This is important.
    
    tdf = tdf.rename(columns={'h1date': 'hdate1', 't1val': 'tval1',
                              'h2date': 'hdate2', 't2val': 'tval2',
                              'h3date': 'hdate3', 't3val': 'tval3'})

   ## Then use the non-numeric portion,  (in this example 'hdate', 'tval') as 
   ## stubnames. The mistake you were doing was using ['date', 'val'] as stubnames.

    df = pd.wide_to_long(tdf, stubnames=['hdate', 'tval'], i='person_id', j='grp').sort_index(level=0)
    
    print(df)
```